# как сделать choicefield autocomplete в django админке?

Tags: python, django

у меня есть собственный лист регионов , и мне нужно сделать autocomplete то есть когда ввожу начальные буквы он должен мне показывать(например , ввожу Ал , он мне должен показывать Алматы или Алтай И так далее) . и это все на админке нужно сделать

[image: вот что сейчас есть]

'''from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Theriology(models.Model):